# Pygame, update() для группы спрайтов работает некорректно

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, спрайт

Занимаюсь по книге 'Эрика Матиза Изучаем python'

Задания:

13-3. Капли: найдите изображение дождевой капли и создайте сетку из капель. Капли должны постепенно опускаться вниз и исчезать у нижнего края экрана.

13-4. Дождь: измените свой код в упражнении 13-3, чтобы при исчезновении ряда капель у нижнего края экрана новый ряд появлялся у верхнего края и начинал падение.

С первым я справился, однако вызов переопределенного update(stars) для класса капли (в коде Star) не совпадает с ожидаемым, т.е. аргументом я передаю группу спрайтов в update(), и ожидаю что вся эта сетка капель изменит свое положение в соответствии с кодом в update (он обновляет положение для каждого спрайта в группе stars = Group() )

Но по итогу пропадают все ряды капель кроме первого ряда с !Отрисовки на экране (выводил в консоль количество созданных рядов и столбцов, с вызовом и без update, всегда одни и те же количества). Ну соответственно оставшийся ряд начинает движение вниз как и было задумано.

game.py

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
import game_functions as gf


def run_game():
        # Иницилизирует игру и создает объект экрана.
        pygame.init()
        ai_settings = Settings()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.scr_width, ai_settings.scr_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        #Создание группы для звезд
        stars = Group()
        gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, stars)
        # Запуск основного цикла игры.
        while True:
            gf.check_events()
            gf.update_stars(stars)
            gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stars)



run_game()
```

game_functions.py

```
import sys
import pygame
from star import Star


def check_events():
    #Обрабатывает нажатия клавиш и события мыши
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()


def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stars):
    #При каждом проходе перерисовывается экран
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    stars.draw(screen)
    # Отображение последнего прорисованного экрана
    pygame.display.flip()

#--------------------------------------------------------------
def get_number_stars_x(ai_settings, star_width):
    #Вычисление количества звезд в ряду
    number_stars_x = int(ai_settings.scr_width / star_width)
    return number_stars_x


def get_number_rows(ai_settings, star_height):
    #Вычисление количества рядов звезд
    number_rows = int(ai_settings.scr_height / star_height)
    return number_rows


def create_star(ai_settings, screen, stars, star_number, row_number):
    #Создание пришельца
    star = Star(ai_settings, screen)
    star.rect.x = star.rect.width * star_number
    star.rect.y = star.rect.height * row_number
    stars.add(star)


def create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, stars):
    #Создает флот пришельцев
    star = Star(ai_settings, screen)
    number_stars_x = get_number_stars_x(ai_settings, star.rect.width)
    number_rows = get_number_rows(ai_settings, star.rect.height)
    print(number_stars_x, number_rows, star.rect.width, star.rect.height)
    for row_number in range(number_rows):
        for star_number in range(number_stars_x):
            create_star(ai_settings, screen, stars, star_number, row_number)


def update_stars(stars):
    stars.update()
```

star.py

```
import pygame

from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Star(Sprite):
    #Класс предстовляющий одну звезду
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        super(Star, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        #Загрузка изображения звезды
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/water.jpg')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Каждая новая звезда появляется в левом верхнем углу
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        #Сохранение позиции
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)


    def check_edges(stars, screen):
        scr_rect = screen.get_rect()
        if stars.rect.top >= scr_rect.y:
            return True


    def update(self):
        self.y += self.ai_settings.img_speed_factor
        self.rect.y = self.y


    def blitme(self):
        #Выводит звезду на экран
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А зачем вы инициализируете свойства класса `self.rect.x` и `self.rect.y` вне конструктора класса?

```
star = Star(ai_settings, screen)
star.rect.x = star.rect.width * star_number
star.rect.y = star.rect.height * row_number
```

Вы ведь внутри конструктора класса `Star` уже инициализируете их, но другими значениями, которые и сохраняете в свойства `star.x` и `star.y`:

```
#Каждая новая звезда появляется в левом верхнем углу
self.rect.x = self.rect.width
self.rect.y = self.rect.height

#Сохранение позиции
self.x = float(self.rect.x)
self.y = float(self.rect.y)
```

И потом вы именно этим значением `self.y`, одинаковым для всех экземпляров объекта `Star` пользуетесь для вычисления поля `self.rect.y`:

```
def update(self):
    self.y += self.ai_settings.img_speed_factor
    self.rect.y = self.y
```

В результате после вызова `update` у вас становится одинаковым и поле `self.rect.y` у всех звёзд.

В общем, мои вам рекомендации:

- Никогда не меняйте свойства класса "вручную" снаружи класса, делайте все изменения состояния объекта исключительно с помощью методов класса
- Создавайте сразу полностью настроенный объект в конструкторе класса, не "донастраивайте" объекты после инициализации класса (даже с помощью методов класса)
- Не множьте сущности без необходимости. У вас свойства `self.x` и `self.y` - вообще лишние, они вас только путают, оставьте только `self.rect.x` и `self.rect.y`, делайте все вычисления непосредственно с ними, ну и инициализируйте эти свойства в конструкторе класса, конечно, а не где-то снаружи.

Answer (score 0):

Когда создаешь одну звезду надо обновить у координаты также как и для х

```
def create_star(ai_settings, screen, stars, alien_number, row_number):
    star = Star(ai_settings, screen)
    star = star.rect.width
    star.x = star_width + 2 * star_width * star_number
    star.rect.x = alien.x
    star.y = star.rect.height + 2 * star.rect.height * row_number
    star.rect.y = star.y
    stars.add(star)
```